# I have a few materials that I want to fade between during an animation

Tags: animation, materials

I have different procedural materials and I want to fade from one to another during an animation. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is add a mix shader in between the two nodes, then you can add keyframes to the factor value by pressing 'I' while hovering over it:

[image]

I hope this helped!